# EMF Multilist sorts data in Viewer

Tags: xml, eclipse-emf

Assuming there is an EMD model which accesses following xml file (simplified):

```
<model>
    <set name="Set1"/>
    <get name="Get1"/>
    <set name="Set2"/>
    <get name="Get2"/>
</model>
```

Now I want a list with all these values in a TableViewer by using a MultiList

```
viewer.setInput(EMFProperties.multiList(
    FeaturePath.fromList(ModelPackage.Literals.DOCUMENT_ROOT__MODEL,
        ModelPackage.Literals.MODEL__SET),
    FeaturePath.fromList(ModelPackage.Literals.DOCUMENT_ROOT__MODEL,
        ModelPackage.Literals.MODEL__GET)).observe(modelRoot));
```

This is all working fine, except for one issue:
The Multilist gathers first all `set` objects, then all `get` objects, but I need to display the objects in the correct order.

What I expect/need:

- Set1
- Get1
- Set2
- Get2

What I get:

- Set1
- Set2
- Get1
- Get2

Is there a way to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You elements are contained by a FeatureMap, so you need to access Group feature to have them in order. Like

```
ModelPackage.Literals.MODEL__GROUP
```

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me to the correct direction. Though, there is still a Problem: I expect the List contains still the same DataTypes (Set/Get), but instead all of them have the DataType `ContainmentUpdatingFeatureMapEntry` this causes Problems since my LabelProvider won't work. I guess I can build s.th. around, but then I still have trouble using the `registerPages` Function for the Master-Details-View. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to unwrap a value, which is wrapped in a feature map entry. Try either AdapterFactoryEditingDomain.unwrap of ConrainmentUpdatingFeatureMapEntry.getValue() (instance method). They will give you unwrapped EObjects. But bewere, that you're using wrapping values when manipulating Containments inside a FeatureMap. To wrap the value back, use AdapterFactoryEditingDomain.getWrapperFor(EObject obj) (instance method)